# position: fixed works like position: absolute in Firefox when using CSS filter

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have read the above question and it works fine on `position: absolute` using CSS filter in Firefox. But `position: fixed` using CSS filter is still not as expected. `position: fixed` using CSS filter in Firefox works like `position: absolute`, like below:

```css
html {
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    height: 100%;
}

img{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
}

div {
  margin-top: 10000px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png">

<div id="b">The end.</div>
```

Could anyone solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS-Filter on parent breaks child positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52937708/css-filter-on-parent-breaks-child-positioning)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work if you don't apply the `filter` to `html` and just apply it to the image. Or if you want to apply this to multiple items, wrap them in an element and apply the filter/positioning to the wrapper.

```css
body {
  min-height: 500vh;
}

img {
  -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png">
```