# Why does applying a CSS-Filter on the parent break the child positioning?

Tags: css, css-position, css-transforms, css-filters

So I have this title-screen "animation" that has the title centered on a fullscreen page and when you scroll down it becomes smaller and remains at the top of the page. Here is a working example with the expected behavior, from which I stripped all unnecessary code to make it minimal:

```js
$(window).scroll( () => {
    "use strict";
    let windowH = $(window).height();
    let windowS = $(window).scrollTop();
    let header  = $("#header").height(); 
    
    if (windowS < windowH-header) {
        $("#title").css("transform", "scale("+(2-(windowS/($(document).outerHeight()-windowH))*2.7)+")");
        $("#header").css("transform", "translateY(0)");
        $("#inside, #content").css({
            "position": "static",
            "margin-top": 0
        });
    } else {
        $("#inside").css({
            "position": "fixed",
            "margin-top": -windowH+header
        });
        $("#content").css("margin-top", windowH);
    }
  
    $("#header").css("position", windowS > (windowH-header)/2 ? "fixed" :"static");
});
```

```css
.fixed {
    position: fixed!important;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.wrapper:before {
    display: table;
    content: " ";
}
.wrapper:after {
    clear: both;
}
#inside {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: lightcoral;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
#header {
    height: 90px;
    top: 0;
    position: sticky;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
#title {
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    transform: scale(2);
}
#content {
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>  
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="inside">
            <div id="header">
                <h1 id="title">Title</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

Next up is the exact same snippet but with one addition: I applied a filter, which is, as far as I'm concerned, purely cosmetic: `filter: brightness(1.3);`.

As you can see below when you scroll half-way through the "animation" the title just disappears. When you inspect the element it still has all its properties but somehow it's gone. This is the same in Firefox and Chrome and I have no idea why. I would appreciate it a lot if someone could post a working snippet with the filter applied and explain why it didn't work before.

```js
$(window).scroll( () => {
    "use strict";
    let windowH = $(window).height();
    let windowS = $(window).scrollTop();
    let header  = $("#header").height(); 
    
    if (windowS < windowH-header) {
        $("#title").css("transform", "scale("+(2-(windowS/($(document).outerHeight()-windowH))*2.7)+")");
        $("#header").css("transform", "translateY(0)");
        $("#inside, #content").css({
            "position": "static",
            "margin-top": 0
        });
    } else {
        $("#inside").css({
            "position": "fixed",
            "margin-top": -windowH+header
        });
        $("#content").css("margin-top", windowH);
    }
  
    $("#header").css("position", windowS > (windowH-header)/2 ? "fixed" :"static");
});
```

```css
.fixed {
    position: fixed!important;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.wrapper:before {
    display: table;
    content: " ";
}
.wrapper:after {
    clear: both;
}
#inside {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: lightcoral;
    filter: brightness(1.3);        /*<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<*/
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
#header {
    height: 90px;
    top: 0;
    position: sticky;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
#title {
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    transform: scale(2);
}
#content {
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>  
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="inside">
            <div id="header">
                <h1 id="title">Title</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 155, accepted):

If we refer to [the specification](https://drafts.fxtf.org/filter-effects/#FilterProperty) we can read:

> A value other than none for the filter property results in the
> creation of a **containing block for absolute and fixed positioned**
> **descendants** unless the element it applies to is a document root
> element in the current browsing context. The list of functions are
> applied in the order provided.

This means that your `position:fixed` element will be positioned relatively to the filtered container and no more the viewport. In other words, it's still fixed but inside its *new* containing block (the filtered container)

Here is a simplified version to illustrate the issue:

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200vh;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.container>div {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>I am fixed on scroll</div>
</div>

<div class="container" style="filter:grayscale(1);">
  <div>I move with the scroll</div>
</div>
```

To fix the issue try to  move the filter to the fixed element instead of its container:

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200vh;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.container>div {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  filter: grayscale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>I am fixed on scroll</div>
</div>
```

---

Here is a non-exhaustive<sup>1</sup> list of the properties that *results in the creation of a containing block for absolute and fixed positioned descendants*

- `filter`
- `transform` <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-1/#containing-block-for-all-descendants)</sup>
- `backdrop-filter` <sup>[ref](https://drafts.fxtf.org/filter-effects-2/#BackdropFilterProperty)</sup>
- `perspective` <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-2/#propdef-perspective)</sup>
- `contain` <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-contain/)</sup>
- `container` <sup>[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74606435/8620333)</sup>
- `transform-style` <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-2/#transform-style-property)</sup>
- `content-visibility` <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-contain/#containment-layout)</sup>
- `will-change` when used with one of the above values

> If any non-initial value of a property would cause the element to generate a containing block for absolutely positioned elements, specifying that property in will-change must cause the element to generate a containing block for absolutely positioned elements. <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-will-change/#will-change)</sup>

<sup>1</sup>: I will try to keep this list up to date.

Comment: Thank you! I still wonder why this is a thing. Wouldn't it be better if this wasn't the case?

Comment: @MiXT4PE it's defined in the spec so it should be like that, you may probably ask why they define it this way .. I am pretty sure there is a reason (probably a complex one) behind this choice.

Comment: What if I cannot move my HTML because it needs to be inside a form which is well inside the filtered element? Is there another solution to this bug in the specs?

Comment: @ygoe first it's not bug, it's by design like many features that we don't like but we should work with (clear float, margin collapsing, etc) so you should adapt your code in order to overcome this. There is no universal solution but depending on your case there is for sure a solution. You may ask a question by adding your particular code in order to see if we can modify your logic to keep your requirement and fix the issue.

Comment: Further context for your answer: [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/w3c/fxtf-drafts/issues/11) added the specification that a containing block is created when `filter` has a value other than `none`. The GitHub issue also has a link to the discussion where this was decided, and [this code example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/mkud1Lnm/1/) ([archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160405103427/http://fiddle.jshell.net/mkud1Lnm/1/)) was used to illustrate the ambiguity the containing block was designed to fix.

Comment: @LonnieBest if you think it's ridiculous, you can raise a github issue and discuss with the community and the users who define the Spec. It's not a group of isolated people taking random desicion without any logical reason. There is always a discussion and a reflection behind. You should probably take note of it before drawing such conclusion

Comment: Spec Issue [402](https://github.com/w3c/fxtf-drafts/issues/402). Firefox bug [1650522](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1650522).

Comment: How to I apply it to the root? I tried doing it to :root but it still moved everything

Comment: @Onir you should not apply it to root. Applying it to root or body make things even worse (related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61265706/8620333)

Comment: I'm trying to get a stylus filter working and I want to invert the whole page but I don't know how to get it working without it messing the positions.

Comment: @Onir I doubt inverting the whole page is the solution. You probably need to implement a dark/light mode so better consider different solution, you can find a lot that rely on changing color using CSS variables

Comment: Oh I managed to get it working on chrome, they work differently it seems.

Comment: content-visibility should be added to this list.

Comment: I'm using JS to position a tooltip next to an element the mouse pointer is over. It has worked very well until I needed to use `filter` elsewhere in the document. getBoundingClientRect() gives me the position relative to the viewport, but `left` and `top` are now relative to the containing block. I suppose I could iterate up the DOM tree, find the offset of the element with filter and compensate for it. Is there a simpler way though?

Comment: Using `offsetParent` to find the offset and compensate for it worked well enough.

Comment: Well, not for Safari…

Comment: `animation` does the same. Please add it to your list (y)

Comment: @DATEx2 no, animation don't do that.

Comment: @TemaniAfif not true, it does. I had this issue yesterday and removing the animation property on one of the parents element sorted the issue.

Comment: @DATEx2 no, it doesn't and here is a proof https://jsfiddle.net/vja168e2/ ... You can even check the specification and you will never find anything about the animation creating a containing block for fixed element. Your issue was not related to the animation but to something else.

Comment: @TemaniAfif there you go https://jsfiddle.net/DATEx2/83n4tygd/7/
Perhaps because the animation has `transform` inside it!

Comment: @DATEx2 it's the transform (like explained in my answer), the animation has nothing to do there. And the fix is to remove `forwards`, not to remove the animation.

Comment: What do you mean by remove `forwards`?

Answer (score 4):

You can make it happen by using `before`. instead of assigning the `filter: brightness(1.3);` to the child element directly. assign color and filter to the `before` of this child element. so your code should be like this:

```
  #inside:before{
    filter: brightness(1.3);
    content: "";
    background-color: lightcoral;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

This will fix the problem.

You should also edit some of your code to make this fully work:

```
#inside{
    position: relative;
}
```

Make the parent position to be relative to make sure the `before` wrap inside its parent.

This solution also works with other filters like `backdrop-filter`.

Answer (score 2):

In order to avoid hard maintenance and different implementation for each browser, you can use a recursive tree traversal function which marks the position 'fixed' nodes and then apply the needed filter properly without destroying the positions.

I used [this](https://github.com/stavrosdro/n-tree-traversal) code in order to apply the 'filter invert' property globally, without hard-coding it to specific parent elements.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to blur or grayscale the entire page except one element, just use `backdrop-filter` instead of `filter`.
At the time of writing Firefox just needs to [ship](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1578503) it by default.

Not working:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
    <style>
    .overlay {
        position:fixed;
        right:10%;
        top:10%;
        bottom:10%;
        left:10%;
        background-color:red;
        z-index:2;
    }
    .overlay ~ * {
        filter: grayscale(50%) blur(5px);
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="overlay">I am not blurred</div>

    <!-- position test -->
    <div style="margin-top:100px;float:right;">
        <div style="background-color:red;position:fixed;top:0;right:0;width:100px;height:100px;"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Working:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
    <style>
    .overlay {
        position:fixed;
        right:10%;
        top:10%;
        bottom:10%;
        left:10%;
        background-color:red;
        z-index:2;
    }
    body:after {
        content:"";
        position:fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        backdrop-filter: grayscale(50%) blur(5px);
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="overlay">I am not blurred</div>

    <!-- position test -->
    <div style="margin-top:100px;float:right;">
        <div style="background-color:red;position:fixed;top:0;right:0;width:100px;height:100px;"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a little update regarding Firefox: it appears it still has not been rolled-out, but may be rolled-out soon.  For updates, see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1578503

Comment: As @Temani Afif backdrop-filter has the same effect as filter