# How to define Opacity by percentage in CSS?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to define opacity in CSS by percentage (eg 30%) in CSS? does not seem to be working, right now I can only conduct it by decimal point.

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/opacity/

```
.test{
   opacity: 0.3;
}
```

**Intended Goal:**

```
.test{
   opacity: 30%;
}
```

Comment: why? these mean the same thing.... you have to go with whats in teh standard.

Comment: From your own link "Values are a number from 0 to 1 representing the opacity of the channel (the "alpha" channel)."

Comment: They are effectively the same thing too so not sure what there is to gain either.

Comment: Just curious: Why would one want to use percentages here in favor of decimals?

Comment: I don't think the downvotes are warranted here - it's possible for a valid question to have an answer that is just "no".

Comment: @WoutervanKoppen because it's more intuitive in some case and it's also possible with opacity

Comment: @doublesharp having an integer `30` or a float `0.3` isn't really the same thing. There is some difference especially when it comes to some complex calcuation and rounding. You have at least the possibility to use 2 more digit with a percentage value since there a factor of `100`

Comment: @Ian but the answer is "yes" here ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use a 0 to 100 range, you can calculate the decimal automatically:

```css
element {
  opacity: calc(40 / 100);
}
```

or you can use a variable to make it clearer:

```css
element {
  --opacity-percent: 40;
  opacity: calc(var(--opacity-percent) / 100);
}
```

But both of these are less clear than just using a decimal like the standard says, so I wouldn't recommend them unless there's a really valid reason.

Answer (score 14):

Using a percentage is fully valid css, according to the spec:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity#Values

> `alpha-value`
>       A `number` in the range 0.0 to 1.0, inclusive, or a `percentage` in the range 0% to 100%, inclusive, representing the opacity of the channel (that is, the value of its alpha channel). Any value outside the interval, though valid, is clamped to the nearest limit in the range.

So, either of these should be okay, according to spec:

```css
.foo {
  opacity: .3;
}

.foo {
  opacity: 30%;
}
```

Keep in mind, though, that if you are using Sass, it will not handle the `percentage` value, and will compile it to `1%`.

Comment: some browsers do not support percentage range in opacity (edge, safari ...)

Comment: Take care, the `mozilla developer network` is not the official documentation of the css standard. Percentages are not valid css for the `opacity` property, accordingly to the real official documentation: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-3/#transparency

Comment: this sass bug is what bugged me for half an hour until I tried the decimal.

Comment: The full browser support can be seen at [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_opacity_percentages): currently it’s only Edge, Firefox and Chrome released since late 2019/early 2020

Comment: I just did a quick test on my mac and it looks like `opacity: n%` now works in Safari too (16.3). [Caniuse says it doesn't](https://codepen.io/RBSLGadellaa/pen/BaPGWoX) and 16.3 is pretty new so you may want to wait a bit before actually putting this in prod :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible if you consider `filter`

```css
.box {
  filter:opacity(30%);
  background:red;
  height:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

You will even have better performance because:

> This function is similar to the more established opacity property; the difference is that with filters, some browsers provide hardware acceleration for better performance.<sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/opacity)</sup>

---

Simply pay attention to some special behavior related to stacking context: [CSS-Filter on parent breaks child positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52937708/8620333)

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, it has to be a number between 0 and 1.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_opacity.asp

I'm not sure why you would want a percent instead of this number considering they are the same thing (just divide by 100).

Answer (score 0):

No, [decimals only](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/REC-css-color-3-20180619/#transparency).

> Any values outside the range 0.0 (fully transparent) to 1.0 (fully opaque) will be clamped to this range.

Answer (score 0):

Despite what the [most popular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60283803/446106) (and [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity#Values)) say,
comments by [leoap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57012564/how-to-define-opacity-by-percentage-in-css#comment107195263_60283803) and
[Charlie Harding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57012564/how-to-define-opacity-by-percentage-in-css#comment115100638_60283803)
have observed that opacity percentages are not officially supported.

[W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-3/#transparency) doesn't mention percentages for opacity, and [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_opacity_percentages) shows mixed browser support for it in the real world, outside of recent Chrome, Edge and Firefox.

[image: CSS property: opacity: Support for percentage opacity values | Can I use... Support tables for HTML5, CSS3, etc]

So if in any doubt about which browsers will see your content, it's best to avoid it and stick with decimals.