# How do I change the go-top:hover Icon color?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to change the go top icon when the cursor is hovering over to a white background and green arrow but the code below does not seem to be working;

```
.go-top:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #069146;
    opacity: 100;
}
```

Instead I am getting an orange arrow. Any advice on how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to set `fill` on `.go-top:hover svg`:

Replace

```
.go-top:hover svg {
  fill: #d65050;
}
```

with

```
.go-top:hover svg {
  fill: #069146;
}
```

`opacity: 100` isn't valid. I think you meant `1`. See [How to define Opacity by percentage in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57012564/how-to-define-opacity-by-percentage-in-css#comment107195263_60283803)

Optionally you can use `white` in `color` instead of `#fff`