# How to make child div absolute for a grand parent div as below structure?

Tags: html, css

How to make child div absolute for a grand parent div as below structure?

We know that here child div is absolute for parent div because parent is relative div but
here is scenario where parent is relative div as along as grand parent also relative div but
and now I want to make child div absolute for grand parent div without changing parent div position.
here is code sample code

```
<!-- grand parent div-->
<div style="position:relative">
  <!-- parent div -->
  <div style="position:relative">
    <!-- child div -->
    <div style="position:absolute">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there any possibility or not?

Comment: Nope! absolute works for its parent `relative`

Comment: You would need to remove the parent relative - is it needed as changing it to static (or default) won't change it's position within the grandparent?

Answer (score 3):

Make the child `fixed` and apply a null transform  on the grand-parent (if you don't already have a transform applied to it) to make it the containing block of the fixed element. With this you will have the expected result.

```css
.grand {
  border:5px solid;
  padding:50px;
  transform:translate(0);
  margin:50px;
}
.parent {
  height:100px;
  border:5px solid red;
}
.child {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:green;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<!-- grand parent div-->
<div style="position:relative" class="grand">
  <!-- parent div -->
  <div style="position:relative" class="parent">
    <!-- child div -->
    <div style="position:fixed" class="child">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It works also with a filter property:

```css
.grand {
  border:5px solid;
  padding:50px;
  filter:opacity(100%);
  margin:50px;
}
.parent {
  height:100px;
  border:5px solid red;
}
.child {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:green;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<!-- grand parent div-->
<div style="position:relative" class="grand">
  <!-- parent div -->
  <div style="position:relative" class="parent">
    <!-- child div -->
    <div style="position:fixed" class="child">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Related to understand the trick: [CSS-Filter on parent breaks child positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52937708/8620333)