# CSS filter:invert not working with background-color

Tags: html, css, sass

I have the following CSS applied to the `<html>` tag: `filter: invert(1);`

All elements get inverted even `background-color` of elements, (Chrome v80)

Once I try the same on Safari iOS 13 / Safari MacOS, every element get inverted except for <html>'s `background-color`

CSS filter property is supported for all browsers I'm running:

https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_filter.

Could someone explain this behavior?

```css
html {
  filter: invert(1);
  /* this background-color does not change on ios+other browsers */
  background: #fff;
  padding: 50px;
}

body {
  background-color: #0000ff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  If it works: color should not be red, background should not be blue
</div>
```

Comment: try to add `html{background:#fff}`

Comment: @TemaniAfif I have updated the snippet, same problem does not get inverted.

Comment: Quite interesting, [same discrepancy happens with `opacity` + `background-color`](https://plnkr.co/edit/mFJwIz6uvXSNOPOJ?open=lib%2Fscript.js), FF will never let opacity affect the html's background, while Chrome will not affect when in the iframe, but will default to white when the page is ran in its own window. And Safari has the inverse behavior of Chrome (which seems more logical IMM). @TemaniAfif any idea what the specs have to say about this?

Comment: Why not use `:root` for this and switch the background with js? That's usually how dark-themes etc are created nowadays if i'm not mistaken.

Comment: Yeah. But i’m thinking of applying the actual color invert applies

Comment: @Joel but since browsers don't act the same, you can't have a solution for one only, it will break the others. The real solution is to not target `:root`, but to have a container inside <body>, so they all act the same, but still this question is interesting as per the found discrepancy, not the trivial issue.

Comment: @Kaiido I guess such behavior can be explained with the background propagation feature where the background of html will be propagated to the canvas and no more belong to html thus the filter won't apply. Here is a trivial example: https://jsfiddle.net/3crns60a/1/ ... The html isn't covering the whole area and only the border is inverted. I would find it illogical if the red color is inverted or if only the red part covering the html is inverted. By the way all my browsers are showing the same result (red not inverted)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Same result here on my ff for android (yep afk now) though can you try the plnkr I linked to before on different browsers, and in framed vs windowed mode? Certainly somethng is going on here, and at least two browsers don't follow the specs. Background propagation is obviously part of the issue, but it doesn't explain all here.

Comment: @Kaiido I am getting the same result in 3 browsers (Chrome, FF, Edge) where the opacity doesn't apply which is correct for me. Don't know your configuration but the browser appying the opacity seems to be the wrong one (like the one applying the filter)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### **TL;DR**: Don't mess too much with `html` element.

The easy workaround is to block `body`'s background propagation to the document's canvas, but make it take the same size as the `html` by removing its margin, and applying all the styles you had on `html` on the body, and the ones you had on the `body` to a wrapper `<div>`.

```css
html {
  /* block body's background propagation */
  background: #FFF;
}


/* move all one layer down */
body {
  filter: invert(1);
  background: #fff;
  padding: 50px;
  /* make it cover the full canvas */
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  background-color: #0000ff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="text">
    If it works: color should not be red, background should not be blue and border should not be white
  </div>
</div>
```

---

#### More in depth observations:

There are a few concepts at play here, and their interaction is not that easy to grasp (at least to me...).

- "Rendering Layers": When painting a page there will generally be several layers of rendering, possibly nested on which effects like filters or opacity will be applied. The specs only define "stacking contexts", for our case here after they are the same thing.
- ["Document's canvas"](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/intro.html#the-canvas): Each document has a background canvas, which is not present in the DOM and which stands as the deepest "rendering layer".
- ["Background propagation"](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#special-backgrounds): Some special elements have special behaviors regarding their CSS `background` property. Notably, `html` and `body` may give their own background to the "document's canvas". The basic workflow is

  - if `html`'s background is not `none` and not `transparent`, use that for "document's canvas".
  - else if `body`'s background is not `none` and not `transparent`, use that for "document's canvas".
  - else do whatever you want (usually browsers render white solid color).
- "Post-Processing" effects like `filter` and `opacity` should apply on a whole "rendering layer" when all its inner content already has been rendered.
- Setting such "Post-Processing` effects on an element should isolate that element and create a new "rendering layer" from it.

Now, it's very unclear how the "document's canvas" should be affected by these "post-processing" effects, and I couldn't find any definitive answer to this case in the specs.

***What's for sure, is that we have [Compat] issues in there...***

Not only not all browsers do follow the same rules, but some browsers will behave differently when the page is presented as a standalone window, or in an iframe.

Since the test results do vary between windowed and framed renderings, and that StackSnippet only allows framed rendering, I am forced to outsource the test case in [this plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/OtY6oGA2yk1WyTsE).

```css
html {
  background: red;
  height: 50vh;
  border: 10px solid green;
}

.opacity {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.filter {
  filter: invert(1);
}

body {
  background: yellow;
  margin: 10vh;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

The results from these tests for majors browsers are:

**When windowed**: (screenshot orders, from left to right: *nothing*, *filter*, *opacity*, *filter + opacity*).

- Firefox doesn't apply neither filter nor opacity to the document's canvas. [image: Firefox screenshots]
- Edge doesn't apply neither filter nor opacity to the document's canvas. (same as Firefox)
- Chrome < 81 doesn't apply neither filter nor opacity to the document's canvas. (same as Firefox)
- Chrome >= 81 applies both filter and opacity to the document's canvas.
  [image: Chrome screenshots]
- Safari does

  - apply the filter uniformly when there is no opacity set.
  - not apply the opacity on the document's canvas
  - create a new layer for `<html>` when opacity is set and applies both opacity and filter on the `<html>`'s background.
                However it now uses `<body>`'s background color as the document's canvas... but let it unaffected by the filter.

  [image: Safari screenshots]

**When framed**: (screenshot orders, from left to right: *nothing*, *filter*, *opacity*, *filter + opacity*).

- Firefox doesn't apply neither filter nor opacity to the document's canvas.
  [image: Firefox screenshots]
- Edge doesn't apply neither filter nor opacity to the document's canvas. (same as Firefox)
- **Chrome (all versions) doesn't apply neither filter nor opacity to the document's canvas.**
  [image: Chrome screenshots]
- Safari does

  - apply the filter uniformly when there is no opacity set.
  - **set the document's canvas to transparent when opacity is set, and create a new layer for `<html>` on which the opacity is applied.**
  - create a new layer for `<html>` when opacity is set and applies both opacity and filter on the `<html>`'s background.
                **However it now sets the document's canvas transparent.**

  [image: Safari screenshots]

---

So once again, I don't know if any result here is per specs, what I know is that as web-authors, we should avoid messing with it when possible.

---

Post-scriptum:

- Here is the [Chromium issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=471333) from which the new Chrome behavior was introduced.
- Here is [a proposal](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/3949) to allow web authors to define the document's canvas background as transparent for some devices.