# Why does filter not applying to body?

Tags: css

Let's say I want to grayscale the whole page, and I apply `filter: grayscale(100%)` to body, and the body background is green:

```
body {
  background: green;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

and I also have an element with pink background:

```
<div style="background: pink; width: 250px; height: 250px"></div>
```

Why does the background staying green, while the pink div is gray?:

```css
body {
  background: green;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<div style="background: pink; width: 250px; height: 250px"></div>
```

By the way, `filter: invert(..)` doesn't apply as well:

```css
body {
    background: green;
    filter: invert(1);
}
```

```html
<div style="background: pink; width: 250px; height: 250px"></div>
```

Tested on Firefox 90.0.1 64bit Win10

Comment: Odd...it appears that the filter only applies to the **contents** of the body and not the body itself.

Comment: @AnonymousCoder It doesn't seem like that. body is still green, not inverted/grayscaled

Comment: [CSS filter:invert not working with background-color](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61265706)

Comment: oh sorry i didn't saw that

Comment: i got this definition from w3 schools: "The filter property defines visual effects (like blur and saturation) to an element (often <img>)."