# Why input with position absolute inside an overflow causes global scrollbar on a page?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, overflow

When I have an input with a `position: absolute` style inside a div that has `overflow: scroll` (or any kind of overflow that is not visible), and when the div is indeed overflowing, the html element gains a vertical scrollbar of the height of the overflowing content.

It is shown in the following snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div style="height: 80vh;display: flex;width: 20rem;">
      <div style="overflow: scroll;">
        <hr style="width: 0; height: 200vh; margin: 0 10rem;" />
        <input style="position: absolute;" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you remove the `<hr/>` element, the global scrollbar disappears because the inner div is not overflowing any more. if you replace the `<input>` element with an empty `<div>` the problem is not showing any more.

My question is:

- Why are global scrollbars appearing (on the `html` element)?
- How can I prevent it? I can set `overflow: hidden` on the html element but sometimes on reload, the page is not scrolled to top and the top of the page is no longer visible. `overflow: clip` is not yet usable.

Background: I have a page with an interface that takes all the visible viewport and there is no page scrollbars. Any scrollable content is managed within the page with overflow properties. I have input elements within that I hide using the `position: absolute` CSS property (among others) to ensure that they are still focusable.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to put a `position: relative` property on the overflow element:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div style="height: 80vh;display: flex;width: 20rem;">
      <div style="overflow: scroll;position:relative;">
        <hr style="width: 0; height: 200vh; margin: 0 10rem;" />
        <input style="position: absolute;" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But it doesn't work with `isolatiob: isolate` although I would have thought it would work:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div style="height: 80vh;display: flex;width: 20rem;">
      <div style="overflow: scroll;isolation: isolate;">
        <hr style="width: 0; height: 200vh; margin: 0 10rem;" />
        <input style="position: absolute;" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Related documentation: [MDN on stacking contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)

Comment: isolation won't work because it establish a stacking context and not a containing block for absolute element. `transform: translate(0);` will work for example ( more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52937920/8620333)