# Absolute positioned elements losing position on active with filter

Tags: html, css

I encountered the following strange situation that I recreated in the following example:

```css
.relative {
    position: relative;
}
.absolute {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 100%;
}
a:active {
    filter: brightness(130%);
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
    <a href="//google.com"><img class="absolute" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/23/Sternbergia_lutea_showing_the_different_parts_of_the_flower.JPG/130px-Sternbergia_lutea_showing_the_different_parts_of_the_flower.JPG" /></a>
</div>
```

On click mousedown event triggers `:active` pseudo class having that `filter` property while the image loses it's absolute position and as a result the link is not even followed. I couldn't find anything about it anywhere, does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the exact reason for it either. However, what you want to be doing is applying the filter to the img not the  tag. Perhaps the behaviour is undefined on an  tag:

```css
.relative {
    position: relative;
}
.absolute {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 100%;
}
a:active img {
    filter: brightness(130%);
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
    <a href="//google.com"><img class="absolute" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/23/Sternbergia_lutea_showing_the_different_parts_of_the_flower.JPG/130px-Sternbergia_lutea_showing_the_different_parts_of_the_flower.JPG" /></a>
</div>
```

That fixes it.

Comment: Thank you, I know how to avoid this situation, but the question remains...My example was random, it happens in various different situations. And I don't think is normal...

Comment: Hmm, so it turns out this is a duplicate. Answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52937708/why-does-applying-a-css-filter-on-the-parent-break-the-child-positioning

Comment: should I delete the question? (I'm not familiar with procedure in this situation)

Comment: No need - it's now closed as a duplicate. That's better than deletion since someone might find your question rather than the previous one.

Comment: Ok, thank you for info.