# Why is translateZ not being applied to the direct parent or its parent?

Tags: html, css, css-position, z-index, css-transforms

So I have a few `div`s with a hierarchy like this:

```
<div class="grandparent">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="uncle"></div><div class="uncle"></div>
</div>
```

My problem is, I have `transform-style: preserve-3d;` applied to the parent, grandparent, and uncles and `transform: translateZ(-2px)` applied to the child. I expect the child to appear behind both the parent, grandparent, and uncles. However, the child appears in front of both the parent and grandparent *and* is *mixing* with the uncles. Basically, the uncles are covering the `border` of the child and the child is covering the `border` of the uncles. I expect that the problem between the child and uncle will be resolved if the child appears behind the parent and grandparent.
All I want is for the child to appear behind the parent and grandparent. I have tried to apply `transform-style: preserve-3d;` to the child as well, but there was no change. I'm assuming there is a problem with some of my styles or timing that I don't realize, so here's a bunch of Javascript which applies each element and their styles (note that you need to wait for a second for the child element to appear):

```js
elements = {};
document.getElementsByTagName("style")[0].innerHTML += `
  .navButton {
    color: white; 
    transition: filter 1.5, background-color 0.3s; 
    background-color: inherit; 
    border: 0px; 
    outline: none; 
    font-family: Cinzel;
    filter: brightness(0%);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }
  .navButton:hover {
    font-size: 35px;
    background-color: rgb(110, 205, 255);
  }
  #child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    transition: top 0.3s, height 0.3s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform: translateZ(-2px);
  }`;
//Navigation bar
elements.navBar = document.createElement("div");
elements.navBar.style.cssText = "position: absolute; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, 0%); display: flex; top: 15px; width: 800px; height: 60px; background-color: rgb(92, 199, 238); filter: brightness(0%); box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px -1px gray; font-family: Cinzel; font-size: 30px; color: white; transform-style: preserve-3d;";
document.body.append(elements.navBar);
// Parent in nav
elements.parent = document.createElement("button");
elements.parent.type = "button";
elements.parent.innerHTML = "Parent";
elements.parent.classList.add("navButton");
elements.parent.style.fontSize = "30px";
elements.parent.style.borderRight = "3px solid rgb(85, 190, 220)";
elements.parent.style.maxWidth = "250px";
elements.parent.style.minWidth = "150px";
elements.navBar.append(elements.parent);
// Uncle One in nav
elements.uncleOne = document.createElement("button");
elements.uncleOne.type = "button";
elements.uncleOne.innerHTML = "Uncle 1";
elements.uncleOne.classList.add("navButton");
elements.uncleOne.style.cssText = "font-size: 30px; border-right: 3px solid rgb(85, 190, 220);";
elements.navBar.append(elements.uncleOne);
elements.uncleOne.style.width = elements.uncleOne.offsetWidth * 1.3;
// Uncle Two in nav 
elements.uncleTwo = document.createElement("button");
elements.uncleTwo.type = "button";
elements.uncleTwo.innerHTML = "Uncle Two";
elements.uncleTwo.classList.add("navButton");
elements.uncleTwo.style.fontSize = "30px";
elements.uncleTwo.style.borderRight = "3px solid rgb(85, 190, 220)";
elements.navBar.append(elements.uncleTwo);
elements.uncleTwo.style.width = elements.uncleTwo.offsetWidth * 1.3;

function lighten() {
  elements.navBar.style.filter = "brightness(100%)";
  elements.parent.style.filter = "brightness(100%)";
  elements.uncleOne.style.filter = "brightness(100%)";
  elements.uncleTwo.style.filter = "brightness(100%)";
  elements.child = document.createElement("div");
  elements.child.id = "child";
  elements.child.innerHTML = "Child";
  setTimeout(() => {
    elements.child.style.cssText = "left: -3px; width: 200px; border: 3px solid rgb(85, 190, 220); background-color: rgb(92, 199, 238);";
    elements.parent.append(elements.child);
    elements.uncleOne.onmouseenter = () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        elements.child.style.top = "60px";
        elements.child.style.height = "80px";
      }, 1);
    }
    elements.uncleOne.onmouseleave = () => {
      elements.child.style.top = "0px";
      elements.child.style.height = "50px";
    }
  }, 1600);
}
lighten();
```

If you hover over Uncle 1, then the child with change its position, hence my need to place it underneath the navBar. It would probably look bit better in fullscreen. [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Rohittt/pen/NWbqzJN).

Comment: it's the filter that create the issue, you need to remove otherwise it will be impossible

Comment: @TemaniAfif so after the elements have brightness 100, I should set it to null?

Comment: yes filter:none will fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `filter` you are applying, it's the culprit. The one applied to `navBar`

```js
elements = {};
document.getElementsByTagName("style")[0].innerHTML += `
  .navButton {
    color: white; 
    transition: filter 1.5, background-color 0.3s; 
    background-color: inherit; 
    border: 0px; 
    outline: none; 
    font-family: Cinzel;
    filter: brightness(0%);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }
  .navButton:hover {
    font-size: 35px;
    background-color: rgb(110, 205, 255);
  }
  #child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    transition: top 0.3s, height 0.3s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform: translateZ(-2px);
  }`;
//Navigation bar
elements.navBar = document.createElement("div");
elements.navBar.style.cssText = "position: absolute; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, 0%); display: flex; top: 15px; width: 800px; height: 60px; background-color: rgb(92, 199, 238);  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px -1px gray; font-family: Cinzel; font-size: 30px; color: white; transform-style: preserve-3d;";
document.body.append(elements.navBar);
// Parent in nav
elements.parent = document.createElement("button");
elements.parent.type = "button";
elements.parent.innerHTML = "Parent";
elements.parent.classList.add("navButton");
elements.parent.style.fontSize = "30px";
elements.parent.style.borderRight = "3px solid rgb(85, 190, 220)";
elements.parent.style.maxWidth = "250px";
elements.parent.style.minWidth = "150px";
elements.navBar.append(elements.parent);
// Uncle One in nav
elements.uncleOne = document.createElement("button");
elements.uncleOne.type = "button";
elements.uncleOne.innerHTML = "Uncle 1";
elements.uncleOne.classList.add("navButton");
elements.uncleOne.style.cssText = "font-size: 30px; border-right: 3px solid rgb(85, 190, 220);";
elements.navBar.append(elements.uncleOne);
elements.uncleOne.style.width = elements.uncleOne.offsetWidth * 1.3;
// Uncle Two in nav 
elements.uncleTwo = document.createElement("button");
elements.uncleTwo.type = "button";
elements.uncleTwo.innerHTML = "Uncle Two";
elements.uncleTwo.classList.add("navButton");
elements.uncleTwo.style.fontSize = "30px";
elements.uncleTwo.style.borderRight = "3px solid rgb(85, 190, 220)";
elements.navBar.append(elements.uncleTwo);
elements.uncleTwo.style.width = elements.uncleTwo.offsetWidth * 1.3;

function lighten() {
  elements.parent.style.filter = "brightness(100%)";
  elements.uncleOne.style.filter = "brightness(100%)";
  elements.uncleTwo.style.filter = "brightness(100%)";
  elements.child = document.createElement("div");
  elements.child.id = "child";
  elements.child.innerHTML = "Child";
  setTimeout(() => {
    elements.child.style.cssText = "left: -3px; width: 200px; border: 3px solid rgb(85, 190, 220); background-color: rgb(92, 199, 238);";
    elements.parent.append(elements.child);
    elements.uncleOne.onmouseenter = () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        elements.child.style.top = "60px";
        elements.child.style.height = "80px";
      }, 1);
    }
    elements.uncleOne.onmouseleave = () => {
      elements.child.style.top = "0px";
      elements.child.style.height = "50px";
    }
  }, 1600);
}
lighten();
```

Related: [Why does applying a CSS-Filter on the parent break the child positioning?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52937708/8620333)