# Material-UI Snackbar on React gets fixed to the bottom of the page

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, snackbar

I am using Material UI Snackbar in a component, but the Snackbar shows up at the bottom of the page and isn't fixed so user will have to scroll to the bottom to see it.

```
<Snackbar>
  open={open}
  autoHideDuration={6000}
  onClose={handleClose}
>
  <Alert onClose={handleClose} severity="error">
    There was an error signin up. Please  try again!
  </Alert>
</Snackbar>
```

Here is the picture:

[image: Snakbar]

Answer (score 0):

By nature `<Snackbar />` sticks to bottom by [`position: fixed`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlYRJ.png).

Maybe one of its parents breaks its `fixed` position, for example by having `transform` or `will-change: transform`.

```
<div style={{ willChange: "transform" }}>
  <Snackbar open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
    <Alert onClose={handleClose} severity="error">
      There was an error signin up. Please try again!
    </Alert>
  </Snackbar>
</div>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-gvlmk?file=/demo.js

---

More info about what breaks `position: fixed`:

- https://dev.to/takaaki_suger/when-position-fixed-is-not-working-7i6
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/52937920/863110