# Pure CSS and HTML problem - Why the :hover status would ruin a position:absolute item in Chrome?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a utility box on the left side of my page, with two buttons: A blue one and a grey one. The grey one has a tooltip within it.

Here is the code:

```css
body {background:black}
#side-root {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:9999;
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
  top: 50%;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 65px !important;
  bottom:auto !important;
  transform:translate(0,-50%);
  left:0;
  padding-right:40px;
}
#side-root a:hover, #side-root b:hover{
  padding-left:9px;
}
#side-root a div, #side-root b div{
  height:45px;
  width:45px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  margin:0 auto;
  background-size:45px
}

.side-a {
  background:#1877F2d6;
  width:100%;
  cursor:pointer;
  backdrop-filter:blur(15px) contrast(5);
}
.side-a:hover {
  background:#1877F2;
  backdrop-filter:none;
}
.side-b {
  background:#B1B1B1d6;
  width:100%;
  cursor:pointer;
  backdrop-filter:blur(15px) contrast(5);
}
.side-b:hover {
  background:#B1B1B1;
  backdrop-filter:none;
}


.b-tooltip {
  position: fixed;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: auto !important;
  height: auto !important;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(173, 168, 168, 0.1);
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  line-height: 18px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
  z-index:9;
  top:4px;
  left:76px;
}

.b-tooltip svg {
  position: static;
  fill: #fff;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="side-root">
  <a class="side-a">
    <div class="side-a-icon"></div>
  </a>
  <b  class="side-b">
    <div class="side-b-icon">
      <div class="b-tooltip">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 38 38"><path d="M19 0C8.5 0 0 8.5 0 19s8.5 19 19 19 19-8.5 19-19S29.5 0 19 0zm0 24.8c-1.6 1.6-4.2 1.6-5.8 0l-5.4-5.4 2.9-2.9 5.4 5.4 11-11 2.9 2.9-11 11z"></path></svg>
        <span>done</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </b>
</div>
```

The expected behavior is to keep the `.b-tooltip` box always fixed. However, it's very strange that if I hover the mouse on the `.side-b`, the `.b-tooltip` box would go up.

What's even weird is that this happens only on Chrome `Version 96.0.4664.55 (Official Build) (x86_64)` :

[image: Unexpected behavior in Chrome]

And even worse, is that on Safari `Version 15.1 (17612.2.9.1.20)`, it's still not right (the problem is that `.b-tooltip` is always on the first blue box, which should be on the second grey box)

[image: Unexpected behavior in Safari]

What I want is:

1. Don't shift the `.b-tooltip` box when I hover
2. Make the `.b-tooltip` box's position related to the second grey box, not the first blue box.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52937920/8620333 : it's the backdrop-filter

Answer (score 0):

Is this that you are looking for?

```css
body {background:black}
#side-root {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:9999;
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
  top: 50%;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 65px !important;
  bottom:auto !important;
  transform:translate(0,-50%);
  left:0;
  padding-right:40px;
}
#side-root a:hover, #side-root b:hover{
  padding-left:9px;
}
#side-root a div, #side-root b div{
  height:45px;
  width:45px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  margin:0 auto;
  background-size:45px
}

.side-a {
  background:#1877F2d6;
  width:100%;
  cursor:pointer;
  backdrop-filter:blur(15px) contrast(5);
  position: relative;
}
.side-a:hover {
  background:#1877F2;
  backdrop-filter:none;
}
.side-b {
  background:#B1B1B1d6;
  width:100%;
  cursor:pointer;
  backdrop-filter:blur(15px) contrast(5);
  position: relative;
}
.side-b:hover {
  background:#B1B1B1;
  backdrop-filter:none;
}



.b-tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: auto !important;
  height: auto !important;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(173, 168, 168, 0.1);
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  line-height: 18px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
  z-index:9;
  top:4px;
  left:76px;
}


.side-b:hover .b-tooltip {
  left: 86px;
}

.b-tooltip svg {
  position: static;
  fill: #fff;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="side-root">
  <a class="side-a">
    <div class="side-a-icon"></div>
  </a>
  <b  class="side-b">
    <div class="side-b-icon">
      <div class="b-tooltip">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 38 38"><path d="M19 0C8.5 0 0 8.5 0 19s8.5 19 19 19 19-8.5 19-19S29.5 0 19 0zm0 24.8c-1.6 1.6-4.2 1.6-5.8 0l-5.4-5.4 2.9-2.9 5.4 5.4 11-11 2.9 2.9-11 11z"></path></svg>
        <span>done</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </b>
</div>
```