# Why is my element's offsetParent its parent static element instead of its fixed grandparent?

Tags: html, css, css-position

UPDATE: I found out the CSS that causes it. It's due to an animation that has `transform` property.

If I disable it, the `offsetParent` goes back to its grandparent. Now I wonder why and there isn't any documentation regarding this behavior.

```js
const child = document.querySelector(".child");

console.log(getComputedStyle(child).position);
console.log(child.offsetParent.className);
```

```css
.container {
  position: fixed;
}

.parent {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

I am having a very strange situation where one of my `absolute` element is positioned against its parent element (which is `static` and has no position set) instead of its grandparent element (which is a `fixed`). I cannot reproduce it so please see this screenshot:

[image]

As per [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetParent):

> A positioned ancestor is either:
>
> - an element with a non-static position, or
> - td, th, table in case the element itself is static positioned.

What is the issue?

Comment: MDN is somewhat out of date of this point. Other styling of the parent element can affect this, not just the position property. What style properties do you have set on the parent element?

Comment: @Alohci I have found it out. It's an animation property but the actual cause is the `transform` property caused by that animation.

Comment: Yes, transform is one such property. There's a list of such properties maintained here by Temani Afif: [Why does applying a CSS-Filter on the parent break the child positioning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52937708/why-does-applying-a-css-filter-on-the-parent-break-the-child-positioning#52937920)

Comment: @Alohci thank you so much. That's a pain. Now I need to think what is the least painful solution. Assuming I need the `parent` (for animation), what should I do to position my `child` with the `container` (i.e. set height to 100% of the `container`)?