# Why my bookmark disappear when applying filter on Wikipedia Dark Mode?

Tags: html, css, wikipedia

English Wikipedia has a gadget you can enable (after you login) that adds Dark Mode.

This is the CSS that is applied to the whole page:

```css
@media screen {
  html {
    height:100%
  }
  html,
  html img,
  html video,
  html ogvjs,
  html svg,
  html iframe,
  html .mw-no-invert,
  html td .diffchange,
  html .mwe-math-element,
  html .wvui-typeahead-suggestion__thumbnail,
  html .skin-minerva .mw-notification-visible .mw-notification-content,
  html .cdx-menu-item__thumbnail,
  html .cx-slitem__image,
  html .mw-mmv-overlay,
  html .mw-mmv-pre-image,
  html .media-viewer .image img,
  html .media-viewer .mw-file-description img,
  html .mw-kartographer-map,
  html .mw-kartographer-mapDialog-map,
  html .oo-ui-searchWidget-results .oo-ui-iconElement-icon,
  html .list-thumb,
  html .ext-related-articles-card-list .ext-related-articles-card-thumb {
    filter:invert(1) hue-rotate(180deg)
  }
  html .skin-vector .mw-logo-wordmark,
  html .skin-vector .mw-logo-tagline,
  html .skin-timeless .mw-wiki-title > img,
  html .wvui-icon svg,
  html .mw-ext-score img,
  html .mw-hiero-table img {
    filter:none
  }
}
```

It reverses the colors with a filter and reverses them back on images. This seems to work like XOR. When applied two times it seems to cancel the effect.

I have a [bookmarklet - Scheme REPL](https://lips.js.org/#bookmark) and When I apply the below CSS in Firefox DevTools:

```css
.shell-wrapper {
  filter:invert(1) hue-rotate(180deg)
}
```

The content of the bookmark disappears. Why does reversing of colors work for images but not for my Bookmark? Why did the bookmark disappear?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52937708/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks, that explains the issue. I've marked my question as a duplicate.